# PHP preg_replace datetime and matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to style MySQL datetime format string to be something like the following:

```
<b>2018-07-09</b><i>10:25:00</i>
```

I'm trying to use `preg_replace()` to replace matched patterns like the following:

```
preg_replace("/([^\s]+)/",\'<b>$1</b><i>$2</i>\',$date)
```

However, the pattern https://regex101.com/r/LLRx3x/1, indicates that there two matches where each one has one group. The first match is the date, while the second is the time. I could not able to utilize `$1` and `$2` to access and replace each match. The above `preg_match` code returns something like:

`<b>2018-07-09</b><i></i> <b>13:25:18</b><i></i>`

So How could I access each match and replace them to get my goal?

Comment: Why not use https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp to "style" your datetimes?

Comment: @bassxzero It is not formatting date time, it is just deal with string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may capture the date and time into separate 2 groups,then you can use `$1` and `$2`:

```
preg_replace('~^(\S+)\s+(\S+)$~', '<b>$1</b><i>$2</i>', $date)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3FQd9z/1) and a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/w9ix9w).

Note that the `$n` replacement backreferences only refer to the corresponding capturing group values, so if you defined one capturing group in your pattern, only 1 capture is accessible with `$1` and `$2` will hold an empty string, i.e. `preg_replace('~^(\S+)\s+\S+$~', '<b>$1</b><i>$2</i>', '2018-07-09 13:25:18')` will yield `<b>2018-07-09</b><i></i>`).

So, the point here is to match both the date and time but capture them into separate capturing groups, and then use the corresponding backreferences accordingly.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1 (later referred to with `$1` backreference): any 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 2 (later referred to with `$2` backreference): any 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Wonderful solution and explanation!